# How do you configure TinyMCE so that it doesnt display BB code?

Tags: drupal, tinymce

I'm having trouble with Tiny MCE 3.2.5. Im using Drupal 6.1.13 and for someone reason when i come to use TinyWYISYG editor, and alter the text to different fonts it always displays it in BB code. I've tried just using HTML source code, but I still get the same problem.
Tried unchecking the boxes on the profile settings so that it doesnt alter any html code that i input.

Also at present using the button options cannot display media and pictures I want to upload.
It always puts them in BB code as well.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a configuration problem rather than a programming one. Take a look at the support questions on the module homepage http://drupal.org/project/tinymce

Comment: On a side note, you may wish to update Drupal to 6.19 and TinyMCE to 3.3 as they fix a lot of bugs etc

Answer (score 4):

Admin -> Site Configuration -> WYSIWYG -> Click 'Edit' on your input format -> Expand 'Buttons and Plugins' -> Uncheck BBCode -> Hit Save -> Rejoice.